# Changing variable value in all subscopes

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have an `ng-repeat` (inner) element within a `ng-repeat` (topmost) element. I want the inner elements list to show only when a relevant topmost element was clicked (that part I got working). The problem I'm having is getting the current open inner element to close when I click another topmost element, or any other element of the UI for that matter.

I tried putting a `closeAll()` function on the whole controller, but it seems to have no effect because it does not affect the nested scopes in any way.

Here's the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mLaN2/3/)

Comment: You can do something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/mLaN2/4/

Comment: @joakimbl that's almost it! How would I go about hiding all the elements when clicked outside of the buttons?

Comment: try this one, it uses the index as the reference instead of a boolean
http://jsfiddle.net/d65yan/mLaN2/5/

Answer (score 0):

The secret to closing all currently open sublists when clicked outside any element is using the `$event.stopPropagation()` call. Combining the answers I got in the comments with this function I came to the following code:
http://jsfiddle.net/mLaN2/6/